# preg_replace spaces with hyphens between [ ]

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to turn enclosed [ ] into relative links. 
    Ex. [canada] = [Canada](/canada)

I am running into difficulties when I have spaces in the country name.

Here is my code:

```
$text = "[dominican republic] is a country. There are too many hyphens here between square brackets. [canada toronto], and [jamaica]. But none after closed   brackets.";

$text = preg_replace_callback("~\[([^\)]*)\]~", function($s) {
    return str_replace(" ", "-", "[$s[1]]");
}, $text);
$text = preg_replace('|(?<![!\\\])\[(([^\s\]]+))\]|', '<a href="/$2" class="linked">$2</a>', $text);

print $text;
```

Here is the outcome:

`<p><a href="/dominican-republic" class="linked">dominican-republic</a>-is-a-country.-There-are-too-many-hyphens-here-between-square-brackets.-<a href="/canada-toronto" class="linked">canada-toronto</a>,-and-<a href="/jamaica" class="linked">jamaica</a>. But none after closed brackets.</p>`

Thank you

Comment: what is your desired output,please place in your code thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it in one pass

```
$text = "[dominican republic] is a country. There are too many hyphens here between square brackets. [canada toronto], and [jamaica].";

$text = preg_replace_callback("~\[([^\]]*)]~", function($s) {
    return '<a href="/'.str_replace(" ", "-", $s[1]).'" class="linked">'.$s[1].'</a>';
    }, $text);

print $text;
```

output:

```
<a href="/dominican-republic" class="linked">dominican republic</a> is a country. There are too many hyphens here between square brackets. <a href="/canada-toronto" class="linked">canada toronto</a>, and <a href="/jamaica" class="linked">jamaica</a>.
```

Comment: Brilliant. I struggled for longer than want to admit. Thank you

Comment: One quick question, would it be possible to remove SEO stop words from the link href but not the name? Have not run into that problem yet but I may in the future

Comment: Make array with stop word and ask in_array, for examle

Comment: To use it into function write `function($s) use ($stop_array) {`

Comment: Thank you. I will certainly explore that. You've helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. Ask if will be questions